# C: Share an instantiation of a struct between 2 different programs that run at the same time

Tags: c, sockets, struct, process, pipe

I need to make a program like this in C:

- Program A starts and does some stuff.
- Waits.
- Program B starts.
- B sends data to A and waits for the response.
- A replys and waits for B.
- B sends data to A and waits for the response.
- A replys and waits for B.
- That process repeats untill B has no more data.

When A starts it creates some child processes and makes an instance of a control block.

For the part that A needs to wait I thought that I could use a condition variable stored in the control block. When B starts waiting it could wake up A so that they can communicate using pipes.

My problem is: How can i make the control block instantiation from program A visible to B? 
I thought of using a header file to be included by both programs but i think that only applies for the visibility of the control block and not the actual instance of it that was previously created. That problem continues in the rest of the program A-B pipe communication cause they need to share 1 specific instance of a Pipe control block.

Is the solution simply a global variable in program A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i make the control block instantiation from program A visible
>   to B?

Shared memory.

Details would depend on your operating system and C implementation, but that's moot because I would not recommend going in this direction in the first place.

> I thought of using a header file to be included by both programs
>   but i think that only applies for the visibility of the control block
>   and not the actual instance of it that was previously created.

Header files play an important role in C programming generally, and they would have a role to play in a shared-memory solution to your problem, but you are correct that merely including the same header does not cause two different programs to share any memory.

> That
>   problem continues in the rest of the program A-B pipe communication
>   cause they need to share 1 specific instance of a Pipe control block.

Why?  The whole idea seems to be predicated on the idea that you will use a condition variable (and therefore also a mutex) to synchronize the activities of the programs, but that appears to be wholly unnecessary.  You're already planning to use pipes, and these constitute a viable synchronization mechanism by themselves.

> Is the solution simply a global variable in program A?

No.  A "global variable", in the sense that that term is generally used in C context, is global only to a single process.  It is not visible or accessible to other processes.

You're making this harder than it needs to be.  A program attempting to read from a pipe (open in the usual, blocking, mode) will *automatically* wait for data to be available.  You do not need any additional synchronization objects to make that happen.

There are two main caveats:

- For bi-directional communication without additional synchronization objects, you generally need a separate pipe for each direction.
- For exchange of messages larger than one byte each, you may need to be prepared to handle partial transfers (by making additional reads until you have transferred and assembled a complete message).  This implies that you must have a way to recognize message boundaries.

Note that the latter of those applies, at least in principle, even if you rely on external synchronization objects.